# get response from soap using curb in ruby

Tags: ruby

I start working on ruby very recently. i written a small code for SOAP client request and response using curb gem. But i am getting some error in response XML.

Code:

```
require 'curb'

c = Curl::Easy.new('http://api.abc.com/service.asmx?wsdl&apikey='+key)
c.multipart_form_post = true
c.http_post(Curl::PostField.content('SOAPAction', 'http://api.abc.com/GetServices'))
c.http_post(Curl::PostField.content('Content-Type', 'application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8'))
c.http_post(Curl::PostField.content('Content-Length', '200'))
c.http_post(Curl::PostField.file('rovi', '/path/data.xml'))
puts c.body_str
```

Error:

```
<soap:Text xml:lang="en">Server was unable to process request. ---&gt; Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.</soap:Text>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: try savonrb.com - there's not way to make your request work without access to the (wsdl of your) service.

Answer (score 1):

You should try http://savonrb.com/ - as far the best ruby library for soap.